# Sending Email to CSV File with AppleScript and Apple Mail

Tags: applescript, apple-mail

I am trying to run an AppleScript that sends emails through Apple Mail. It appears to be working properly, however I am seeing an error when I run the script.

**This is the error I am seeing:**

```
error "Can’t get text item 1 of \"\"." number -1728 from text item 1 of ""
```

**This is my script:**

```
set csv to read "/Users/Username/Documents/file.csv" as «class utf8»
set text item delimiters to ","
repeat with l in paragraphs of csv
    tell application "Mail"
        tell (make new outgoing message)
            set subject to "subject"
            set content to "content"
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:text 
            item 1 of l}
            send
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

**This is my CSV:**

```
email1@gmail.com
email2@gmail.com
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of `text item 1 of l` is literally just `text item 1 of` and then whatever the text is—that is, it hasn’t been dereferenced to a simple string. Most of the time this is fine, but some actions won’t accept text unless it’s been dereferenced. In this case, you can use `text item 1 of l as string`, i.e.:

```
make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:text item 1 of l as string}
```

Note that in your example above, the more simpler form of just `l` also works:

```
make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:l}
```

but I’m assuming this was a simplified example and your real use case involves extracting text from the CSV file.